# One circle and line inside it with radius 56

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, line, geometry

How to draw line inside circle, line will be visible only inside circle and I need to have  control on line angel. Let say one circle and line inside it with angel 56. How to do this in C# WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put an `Ellipse` and a `Line` in a Panel that lets them draw on top of each other (such as a Grid), and adjust the parameters to whatever you want.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform  Angle="56" CenterX="28" CenterY="28"/>
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
    <Ellipse Height="56" Width="56" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" />
    <Line X1="1" X2="55" Y1="28" Y2="28" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" />
</Grid>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: I have one mistake, i didn't mean radius of circle 56, what I mean is line angle 56. My mistake.

Comment: @IvanTanasijevic In that case, just apply a Layout Transform to the entire Grid to rotate it to whatever angle you want (see update to answer)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in XAML, do it like this:

```
 <Line X1="1" X2="55" Y1="28" Y2="28" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2"  >
        <Line.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform  Angle="56" CenterX="50" CenterY="50"/>
        </Line.LayoutTransform>
 </Line>
```

Comment: The parameters are incorrect. The rendered line doesn't go through the middle of the circle.

Comment: you're right, I didn't set the offset correctly, sorry. Anyway your way works fine, so I'm not updating my source ;)

Comment: To be fair, I forgot about Layout Transforms and was about to figure out the math for the Line till I saw your answer, so +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you read through the respective overviews you should be able to manage: [Geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751808.aspx) & [Shapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx)